# Monitoring ASP.NET Applications hosted on IIS 6.0?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

We have 8 ASP.NET applications hosted on IIS 6.0 in windows 2003 server.We found that IIS Application pool process(W3WP.EXE) is consuming 95% CPU utilization during business hours.We are unable to trace out which ASP.NET application is causing this.We have Database server placed in another server which is in same network.Please let us know how to identify the problematic application using Performance Monitoring tool or some other process.

So far we have identified some unclosed sql connections in different applications and fixed them.However we face the same issue.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

ASP.NET Framework : 2.0 and 3.5 
DATABASE          : SQL SERVER 2005 and 2008

Comment: During the peak, just pause one by one the sites, to find the bad one. Its sounds very bad- but this is the faster and easier way. Ones you find it, then you can trace the sql to see whats is eating this process.

Answer (score 0):

Look into ANTS Performance Profiler. It's fairly inexpensive, and it does a good job of identifying bottlenecks.

As for IIS, get the PID in Task Manager for that process and then check COM+ Manager to
find out which site it is. You may also want to try moving each site into high isolation, and then check the IIS logs to figure out which application is causing the problem.